# Look for count when selecting a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    DECLARE @tmDate datetime
       ,@nBranchId int

SELECT  @tmDate = GETDATE()
       ,@nBranchId = 3483


SELECT  strMessage = CASE WHEN xpr.fRevaluationPrice <> d.fUpplupenRanta THEN
                    d.strInstrument +' in ' + f.strShortName + ' has not been saved. it currently has incorrect fixing in XP_Results: ' + CONVERT(varchar, xpr.fRevaluationPrice) + ' should be: ' + CONVERT(varchar, d.fUpplupenRanta)
                    ELSE ''
                    END     
FROM    dbo.Deals AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.XP_Results AS xpr ON 1=1
    AND xpr.strPaperId = CONVERT(varchar, d.nTransactionId)
    AND xpr.nInstrId = d.nInstrId
    AND xpr.tmDate = CONVERT(datetime, d.strMotpartKIkod) --'20140404'
INNER JOIN dbo.Folders AS f ON 1=1
    AND f.nId = d.nFolderId
WHERE 1=1
and d.nBranchId = @nBranchId
AND d.nInstrId = 11
AND d.nInternalTrans = 3
AND d.nIndex = 1
```

Is it possible to somehow check the count for the THEN and ELSE inside the CASE?
The problem now is that about thousand rows are selected and they are all mixed up, and I wan't to see how many of each there is

Comment: I think u can simply count for balnks and remaining will from then statement.

Comment: Do you really need that message or only the count?

Comment: Right now, only the count

Comment: But I need the count from inside that CASE WHEN, so I can see how many rows that have the message, or the empty ELSE ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your case inside a count like this

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN xpr.fRevaluationPrice <> d.fUpplupenRanta THEN 1 ELSE null END)
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN xpr.fRevaluationPrice <> d.fUpplupenRanta THEN null ELSE 1 END)
FROM...
```